# How to make Flask-bootstrap use venv files instead of system files

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently learning web development through O'Reily's Flask Web Development book. In the flask-bootstrap section, he does this:

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
```

I run python 2.7 in a virtual environment. Running which python gives me this when I have my venv activated:

```
/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/venv/bin/python
```

I installed flask-bootstrap in the venv as stated in the book by doing this:

```
(venv) $ pip install flask-bootstrap
```

and flask-bootstrap successfully installed my in venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages. However, when I run my webpage using service apache2 reload I get a 500 internal server error. Checking the error logs give me this:

Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsCgI.jpg

showing that the system tries to use system files to access flask-bootstrap instead of the venv, so the website crashes because I didn't have flask-bootstrap installed in my system files. (I ended up having to install it there though.)

How would I make the system use my venv's flask-bootstrap rather than the system file's?

Comment: Whats your file structure? the error says you can't find the "bootstrap/base.html" file. is that in the working directory? i'm not sure this is to do with your virtual environment.

Comment: ah sorry i think i might the wrong end of the stick, I haven't really seen people do what your asking. if there is a file in venv you would need to change the extends to "venv/<path to flask bootstrap>/bootstrap/base.html"